# What's the usage of 야 between a verb and past perfect marker "했었던"?

Tags: grammar, conjugation, lyrics

There is a Korean song that i get addicted to it these day, so i said way not try to get what it says, so i started to analyse it, and i had to say Korean is truly a hard one. 
well here is where i get stuck again:

> 말해**야** 했었던

- 말해: to say
- 야: ?
- 했었던: for past perfect

Here is the context (the song lyrics) :

> 아무리 외쳐봐도
>
> 너에겐 들리지 않나 봐
>
> 매일 속으로만
>
> 눈빛으로만
>
> 말해야 했었던
>
> 널 향한 사랑의 말이야

Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's focus on this final phrase:

> 말해야 했었던 널 향한 사랑의 말이야

First off, see that `의 말이야` is a form of `that's what i'm talking about`.
In other words, `사랑의 말이야` is then, `love is what I'm talking about`.

Now, getting closer to your question surrounding `(아/어)야 했었던`, let's first point out that **everything in this phrase before `사랑` modifies that noun** *(which obviously means "love")*.

---

There are two modifying phrases for love:

> 말해야 했었던
>
> 널 향한

Let's take the 2nd one first since it's easier: `널 향한` is just `to your direction`, so the song is saying *that love they're talking about is meant for/in the direction of "you/너"*.

---

Now for the trouble spot: `던` vs `았(었,였)던`.

---

### ~던 - A reminisced past action or continued action from the past is stated

Here are some examples:

> 이 음악은 내가 자주 듣던 것입니다 - I used to listen to this music often.
>
> 여기 있던 책을 누가 가져 갔나요? - Who took the book that was here?

---

### ~았(었,였)던 - A past action more clearly conveyed as having completed

> 떠들썩 했던 방이 갑자기 조용해졌어요 - The classroom which was noisy suddenly quietened down.
>
> 3년 전에 해어졌던 친구에게서 전화가 왔습니다 - I got a phone call from a friend who left three years ago.

** *examples from Korean Grammar for International Learners, Yonsei University Press, 1988*

---

### 말해야 했었던 사랑

We've left out so far the `(아/어)야 해` portion of this, but that just means (as I think we already know) that one "must" do something.

To put all the pieces together then we have

> 말 + 해야 (하다) + 았(었,였)던 + 사랑

which we might piece together in pseudo language as

> Things to say + must/needed to + recalling + love

which makes no sense of course, but that's because the ordering is off...but it should more properly translate to something like

> ***the love that I should have (completely) told you about***

Comment: @habibhassani It's a great lyric, very beautiful.  Thank you for sharing it!

Comment: Yeah it really is, i'm glad that you like it

Answer (score 2):

말해: to say

말해야 해: have to say

말해야만 해: have to say(emphasis)

말해야 했어: had to say

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank's it helped a lot, but what does it all means => "말해야 했었던"

Comment: 말해야 했어 and 말해야 했었어 are almost the same. but grammatically, 말해야 했었어 is closer to 'had had to say'.

and..'~던' is the same with 'that' in this sentence 'it is the word of love that I had had to say'